# JS/Chrome: chrome.extension.getURL in loaded JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have my extension that loads JS file to website by adding  tag.

But this JS script is loading images from extension directory, but it can't, because it doesn't know extension directory.

I can't use chrome.extension.getURL because it doesn't work.

Comment: "because it doesn't work" - probably it does work. Any error in the console?

Comment: Probably you would need to post a message to the background page to have it post back the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found non-optimal solution:

```
function geturl(url)
{
var path = ($('script[src$=jquery.lightbox-0.5.js]').attr('src')).split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')+'/'
return path+url;
}
```

It works, but it doesn't look optimal for me.